# How to Junit test servlet filter which has specific response

Tags: testing, servlets, junit, mockito, servlet-filters

What is the best way to unit test this code?  I need to establish a consistent check for httpResponse which sendError() when condition is true.  Thanks in advance!

Edit:  Unfortunately, this filter is not with Spring MVC so my choice is limited.

```
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain filterchain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    String ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
    if( SomeParameterCheckingFunction ((request)) ) {
        logger.error("Error detected! Time: " + new Date().toString() + ", Originating IP: " + ipAddress);
        if (response instanceof HttpServletResponse){
            HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
            httpResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN,"You are not allowed to access the server!");
        }
    }
    filterchain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

For example when using the **Mockito** mock framework, the provided `doFilter()` method could be JUnit tested using below test case:

```
@Test
public void testDoFilter() throws IOException, ServletException {
    // create the objects to be mocked
    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
    HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = mock(HttpServletResponse.class);
    FilterChain filterChain = mock(FilterChain.class);
    // mock the getRemoteAddr() response
    when(httpServletRequest.getRemoteAddr()).thenReturn("198.252.206.16");

    AccessFilter accessFilter = new AccessFilter();
    accessFilter.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse,
            filterChain);

    // verify if a sendError() was performed with the expected values
    verify(httpServletResponse).sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN,
            "You are not allowed to access the server!");
}
```

Comment: Why do you mock `getRemoteAddr()`. It seems like that isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

One option might be to pull the definition of `SomeParameterCheckingFunction` out of the filter itself (and consume it in the filter).  Then, you could separately unit test that logic.  But, I'm not sure this will be sufficient for you.

Another option might be to test the filter class using Mockito.  This would involve some labor, mocking the request, response, filterchain, logging, and such.  You should be able to verify the response.sendError() call afterwards something like so (assumes static import of Mockito.* methods):

```
//setup mock with concrete class for instanceof check
ServletResponse resp = mock(HttpServletResponse.class);

//define behavior for desired method with void return type.  this appears optional for mocks.
//doNothing().when(resp).sendError(anyInt(), anyString());

//your test here, passing in resp       
if(resp instanceof HttpServletResponse) resp.sendError(400, "blah");

//verify method was called      
verify(resp).sendError(400, "blah");
```

There may or may not be a way to test your filter with [HttpUnit](http://httpunit.sourceforge.net/), but that might not meet your desire for a proper unit test.

Comment: I already have another unit test against the SomeParameterCheckingFunction() so I can easily mock it with Mockito.  Having the ability to verify response.sendError() will be an ideal test case but I am completely stumped on how to do that.  Can you show me the technique on how I might be able to verify response.sendError() in junit after the filter is called?  Tnx!

Answer (score 0):

Updated Feb 2018: [OpenBrace Limited has closed down](https://closingbraces.net/openbrace/), and its ObMimic product is no longer supported.

Here's an example of how you could test the "sendError" using my [ObMimic](http://www.openbrace.com) library of out-of-container test-doubles for the Servlet API.

First, some notes on the given doFilter code:

- "((request))" is presumably meant to just be "(request)".
- The nature of "logger" isn't shown, so I've ignored that for now as irrelevant.
- The filter as given will check non-HTTP requests but if they're rejected the usual log message is written but then sendError is skipped and the normal processing carried out instead. Depending on what you're trying to do, you might want to reject non-HTTP requests up-front, or not check them at all, or do some other type of rejection in place of "sendError". For now I'm assuming we're only interested in how to test "sendError" on HTTP requests.
- The example test below has shown that even when sendError is called the processing still drops through to the normal "doFilter" call. Assuming this isn't intentional, the "sendError" should be followed by a "return", or "doFilter" should be in an "else" clause.

For the example code below:

- I've used JUnit as the test framework, but it could just as well be TestNG or anything else.
- For "SomeParameterCheckingFunction", I've just used one that returns true if the remote IP address is "1.1.1.1".
- "sendError" produces an HTML response that displays the given message. For this example I just check that the response body contains the given message. If you instead wanted to check what parameter values were passed to "sendError", the "Professional Edition" of ObMimic has a "history" feature that would let you do that. Or you could do a "sendError" on a separate response instance and then check that the response bodies match exactly.

Anyway, here's the example code:

```
package com.openbrace.experiments.examplecode.stackoverflow13365536;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import com.openbrace.experiments.examplecode.stackoverflow13365536.YourFilter;
import com.openbrace.obmimic.mimic.servlet.FilterChainMimic;
import com.openbrace.obmimic.mimic.servlet.FilterConfigMimic;
import com.openbrace.obmimic.mimic.servlet.ServletMimic;
import com.openbrace.obmimic.mimic.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestMimic;
import com.openbrace.obmimic.mimic.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseMimic;
import com.openbrace.obmimic.support.servlet.EndPoint;
import org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Example tests for {@link YourFilter#doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse,
 * FilterChain)}.
 *
 * @author Mike Kaufman, OpenBrace Limited
 */
public class YourFilterTest {

    /** The filter to be tested by this instance's test. */
    private YourFilter filter;

    /** The "mimic" request to be used in this instance's test. */
    private HttpServletRequestMimic request;

    /** The "mimic" response to be used in this instance's test. */
    private HttpServletResponseMimic response;

    /** The filter chain to be used in this instance's test. */
    private FilterChainMimic filterChain;

    /**
     * Set up for this instance's test by creating an initialized filter and a
     * request, response and filter chain for use in the test.
     *
     * @throws ServletException if the filter's init method throws such an
     *     exception.
     */
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws ServletException {
        /*
         * Note that for this example's simple filter and tests:
         * - We don't need anything particular in the filter's FilterConfig.
         * - We don't need any particular ServletContext, so we can leave
         *   ObMimic to use its default ServletContext throughout.
         * - We don't need to retain any references to the filter's FilterConfig
         *   or ServletContext.
         * - We can use a FilterChainMimic with default values as the filter
         *   chain. This has a ServletMimic as the next thing in the chain, and
         *   ServletMimic keeps a count of the calls to its service method, so
         *   we can use this to check whether the filter chain's doFilter has
         *   been invoked.
         */
        filter = new YourFilter();
        filter.init(new FilterConfigMimic());
        request = new HttpServletRequestMimic();
        response = new HttpServletResponseMimic();
        filterChain = new FilterChainMimic();
    }

    /**
     * Test the doFilter method with an example request for which
     * SomeParameterCheckingFunction returns true (so that the FORBIDDEN
     * response should result).
     *
     * @throws ServletException if the servlet throws such an exception.
     * @throws IOException if the servlet throws such an exception.
     */
    @Test
    public void testYourFilterWithForbiddenRequest()
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        // Configure the request so that SomeParameterCheckingFunction will
        // return true, which for purposes of this example is triggered by a
        // particular "remote address".
        request.getMimicState().setRemoteEndPoint(
            new EndPoint(null, "1.1.1.1", null));

        // Invoke the doFilter method.
        filter.doFilter(request, response, filterChain);

        // Check that the response is now FORBIDDEN, and that its HTML content
        // does include the expected text message.
        int responseCode = response.getMimicState().getHttpStatusCode();
        String responseBody = response.getMimicState().getBodyContentAsString();
        String expectedMessage = "You are not allowed to access the server!";
        assertEquals("Response has incorrect status code",
            HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN, responseCode);
        Assert.assertThat("FORBIDDEN response does not include expected message",
            responseBody, CoreMatchers.containsString(expectedMessage));

        // Check that the filter chain was not invoked. As we've used a
        // FilterChainMimic with default values, its "target" is a ServletMimic,
        // so we can just check if there have been any calls to that Servlet.
        ServletMimic targetServlet
            = (ServletMimic) filterChain.getMimicState().getTarget();
        boolean filterChainInvoked
            = targetServlet.getMimicState().getServiceCount() > 0;
        assertFalse("FORBIDDEN response but filterChain.doFilter still called",
            filterChainInvoked);

    }

}
```

If you want to try it, there are full details of ObMimic and a free download at the [ObMimic](http://www.openbrace.com) website.